# Extract non English characters, except white spaces from author names in R

Tags: r, regex

I have the following data:

```
authors <- c("Fernando Carré", "Adrüne Coça", "Pìso Därço")
```

And I want to extract non-english characters and convert them into ASCII, but without the spaces. This is what I have tried:

```
gsub("[^[:alnum:]]","",authors)
```

But it returns:

```
[1] "FernandoCarré" "AdrüneCoça"    "PìsoDärço"
```

It should return:

```
"Fernando Carre" "Adrune Coca", "Piso Darco"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Onyambu correction, the following statement is not correct

<strike>The expression `[[:alnum:]]` is made for the package `stringr` only. It cannot be used in other packages. Hence we can use</strike>

But here is what I got from the console.

```
> authors <- c("Fernando Carré", "Adrüne Coça", "Pìso Därço")
> iconv(authors ,to="ASCII//TRANSLIT")
[1] "Fernando Carre" "Adrune Coca"    "Piso Darco"    
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: The expression `[[:alnum:]]` is a POSIX regex and can be used in R without any package. So your firat statement is incorrect. Although it can not be used here since this problem relates to encoding and not translation/substitution

Comment: I'm afraid that the answer is not correct, the result was: `[1] "Fernando Carr'e" "Adr\"une Coca"   "P`iso D\"arco"`